# Can we enhance the custom filter with question age?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, custom-filter

Custom filters are awesome! They really help me focus on just the questions I'd like to, but I'm missing one key filter: question age.

Why? Well frankly I am interested in questions sorted by 'most votes' or 'most frequent' to see if I can answer a popular (and thus probably hard) unanswered question, but the problem is that right now you only get the *all time* highest voted/frequented questions, which often have gone unanswered for a long time for a good reason.

I would be very interested to know, for example, what some highly voted questions in the tag [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) in the last day/week/month are.

Comment: Just do this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20%5bpython%5d%20score%3a10

Answer (score 4):

[Use this filter](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20%5bpython%5d%20score%3a10):

```
is:q [python] score:10
```

And click on the Newest tab to filter the newest ones.

I also think it's relevant to note that, if you want to, you can get emails from Stack Overflow every week or so that note the most popular questions in your watched tags.

Also, as Makyen said in the comments section, you can use the `created` and `lastactive` search operators in SE search. These take specific dates and are more accurate when I tested them.

Comment: If you're going to suggest SE search, then you should probably mention the `created:` and `lastactive:` search operators, which can take specific dates, date ranges, and/or use the relative dates `1y`, `1m`, and `1d`. There's more information in the "Advanced Search Options: Dates" section of the ["How do I search?" page"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).